# Swift: Using Extensions in NSPredicate

Tags: swift, predicate

Could I do the following Predicate in Swift 4 to the following string 'name':

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "name.dropLast() = %@", searchText)
```

Basically, could I add the extension 'dropLast()' inside the predicate? If not, what is an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Could I do the following"

No. NSPredicate comes with its own completely specified language. Predicate strings must conform to that language; otherwise, they cannot be parsed.

> "If not, what is an alternative?"

An alternative to do *what*? You are not telling us anything about the goal here. For example, instead of calling `NSPredicate(format:)`, you might be able to call `NSPredicate(block:)` which lets you write the predicate test in Swift code. But you can't do that in all situations. And you have not said what your situation is.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear about the alternative. So in my predicate, I would want to drop the last character of 'name'. Only then would I want to match that result with 'searchtext'. Since I cannot use 'dropLast()', how else could I match the first few characters less the last character using NSPredicate? Hope that clarifies.

Comment: Yes but in what situation are you using this NSPredicate? What will you hand it to?

Comment: Ah okay. I'm using this to predicate my fetch request from core data. So for example: let request = NSFetchRequest<Users>(entityName: "Users")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "id.dropLast() = %@", "searchText")

Comment: Yes, well, “NSPredicates created with predicateWithBlock: cannot be used for Core Data fetch requests backed by a SQLite store.” so you’re stuck using the format language. You might be able to make some headway by using a MATCHES expression, but you can’t magically introduce Swift into the mix.

Comment: Oh bummer. Alrighty, thank you so much for the advice and tips. Will see what MATCHES can do :)

Comment: Alternative just fetch more objects than you really need and filter the result.